# Dynamically assigning image to CustomCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have different texts in my custom cells in my UITableView, each text has a category. according to category a certain image is assigned to UIImageView in my CustomCell like that:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CCell";

// Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


}

// Configure the cell.
cell.primaryLabel.text = [self.arrayWithTextsFromSelectedCategory objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
NSString *keyForText=[self.arrayWithTextsFromSelectedCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
categoryForPicture=[dicWithTitlesAsKeysAndCategoriesAsValues objectForKey:keyForText];

//cell.categoryImg=[dicWithTitlesAsKeysAndCategoriesAsValues objectForKey:keyForText];
NSLog(@"Current category!!! %@", categoryForPicture);
NSLog(@" %@ ", keyForText);
//NSString *textToExtract;
//textToExtract=[self.texts objectForKey:keyForText];

cell.secondaryLabel.text=[self.texts objectForKey:keyForText];
if (categoryForPicture==@"Стихи") 
{
    NSLog(@"Assigning proper image!!");

        cell.iconImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"stixi.png"];
}
if (categoryForPicture==@"Анекдоты") 
{
    NSLog(@"Assigning proper image!!");

    cell.iconImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"jokes.png"];
}
else 
{

        cell.iconImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"stand_icon.png"];
}



//cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"];

//cell.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]]];
return cell;
```

}
still doesn't work... any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is your string equality check...this categoryForPicture==@"Анекдоты" will return true only if the two are the same object, which will never be the case here, you want to us NSStrings isEqualToString: in order to accomplish your goal... so

```
[categoryForPicture isEqualToString:@""]
```

hope that helps

Comment: and please dont use imageNamed: instead user imageWithContentsOfFile: to avoid image caching - doing this will save your runtime memory..!!